# z-index and opacity issues

Tags: html, css, z-index, opacity

I'm trying to make a wrapper at the back off all of my DIV's that will appear transparent (opacity: 0.6), but everything in front of that is appearing transparent too.

Any ideas how to fix this?

You can find the example here: http://testing.squaretise.com/ (I have given the wrapper (#wrap) a red border so you can interpret easier)

Comment: can you post some codes?

Comment: could you please post the code?

Meanwhile, for understanding stacking order of elements with z-index and how opacity will create a new sub stacking context, you can refer this article : https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use instead of:

```
opacity: 0.6;
```

this:

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
```

The color is in RGB and the last digits are for the transparency level.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to position your transparent div absolutely.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency explains how the descendants pick up the transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is inherited. If the parent is see through, so are the children.

A better way to do this is to remove `opacity` and set the background color to be transparent:

```
.foo {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Comment: _“Opacity is inherited”_ – no, it is not (not in the sense that CSS defines “inheritance”.) If it was, a parent having `opacity: .5` set would mean the child would have that same value automatically as well (if it doesn’t have its own value set), and so the opacity for the child content would be `.5 * .5 = .25` – because opacities are _multiplied_. Instead, the child has the default value of `1`, and therefor its content gets the same opcaity value applied as the parent, `.5 * 1 = .5`

Answer (score 0):

You should use transparent background, instead of opacity.
Background-image is the best way if you want to support IE8. (CSS3 Colours: http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba)

Use data-uri for better performance.

Answer (score -1):

You could even do it with `opacity`. Here's an example:

### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <div id="contentOrWhatever">
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    z-index:0;
}
#wrapper {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0.6;
}
#contentOrWhatever {
    z-index:99;
    opacity:1;
}
```

So `#wrapper` ist now transparent and is ALWAYS behind `#contentOrWhatever`.
Hope I could help you.